# Negative values in Elasticsearch range queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have find this problem while making a watch in Elasticsearch, this is my query:

```
"body": {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
        "range": {
          "percent": {
            "lt": 100
          }
```

It returns successfully every document with percent between 0 and 99, however it ignores those with negative value. The "percent" field is mapped as long number in the index.

Can you help me?
Thanks

**Edit:** Return of executing "curl -XGET localhost:9200/monthly-tickets-2018-06"

```
{
  "monthly-tickets-2018-06": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "monthly_tickets": {
        "properties": {
          "percent": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "priority": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "project": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "ref": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1528946562231",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "aIfLjFwqS_aCzQFvZm0L5Q",
        "version": {
          "created": "6020399"
        },
        "provided_name": "monthly-tickets-2018-06"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`?

Comment: Hi, this is the return:

Comment: {"monthly-tickets-2018-06":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"monthly_tickets":{"properties":{"percent":{"type":"long"},"priority":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"project":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"ref":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"timestamp":{"type":"date"}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1528946562231","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"aIfLjFwqS_aCzQFvZm0L5Q","version":{"created":"6020399"},"provided_name":"monthly-tickets-2018-06

Comment: Please move that to your question, it is more legible

Comment: Oops, sorry, I have added it.